# Tomcat server not starting up after changing maxPostSize in eclipse

Tags: tomcat

In `Servers\Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost-config\server.xml`

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" maxPostSize="0" />
```

after adding `maxPostSize=0` server is not starting up!What should i do about this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: thanks for the info

Comment: Check catalina.out log file

Comment: i cant find a log file but when i run eclipse it says configuration may be corrupt or incomplete